# How to install LieART and other packages with Mathematica Online

Tags: packages, wolfram-cloud, mathematica-online

I was wondering if it was possible to integrate a program and documentation package called LieART (http://lieart.hepforge.org/) into Mathematica Online. LieART is a package specially made for Mathematica, but I am not able to integrate it into Mathematica Online. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 5):

Installing packages and applications works the same way in Mathematica Online as with the desktop Mathematica.  Place the package directory into the following location:

```
FileNameJoin[{$UserBaseDirectory, "Applications"}]
```

Limitations:

- Some packages don't follow the standard structure, or require additional setup steps.  Read the installation instructions for each package to find out if this is the case.
- Mathematica Online only supports packages that are written purely in the Wolfram Language.  Anything that has parts written in C or Java won't work.  Many Mathematica packages on Hepforge rely on such external components and can't be used with Mathematica Online.
- I don't think that it is possible to integrate the documentation into the online documentation browser.  Or at least I didn't succeed.

---

#### Example with LieART

LieART follows the standard application structure.  Its installation instructions tell you to use File -> Install...  That method only works with packages that follow conventions.

This package comes as an archive.  We have to get the archive into `$UserBaseDirectory/Applications`.  You can either use the file browser to upload it there (evaluate `UserBaseDirectory` to see where you have to browse), or you can download directory with a Mathematica command.  I am going to show the latter.

Enter the application directory:

```
SetDirectory@FileNameJoin[{$UserBaseDirectory, "Applications"}]
```

Download the archive:

```
URLDownload["http://www.hepforge.org/archive/lieart/LieART-1.1.5.tar.gz","LieART-1.1.5.tar.gz"]
```

Extract it:

```
ExtractArchive["LieART-1.1.5.tar.gz"]
```

Check that everything is in place using the file browser on the right, or using the command line:

```
FileNames[]
FileNames["LieART/*"]
```

The package is now ready to use.  Load it with

```
Needs["LieART`"]
```

Check what package symbols are available using

```
Information["LieART`*"]
```